# Android Spinner Custom?

Tags: android, spinner

I am trying to create a spinner that looks exactly like the one in this android example, but not sure how or if it has to be custom?  I cant imaging it would have to be a custom layout since it is shown this way in their example...

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html#Populate

[image]

I am not concerned with how the list looks, but just the way the spinner looks with the lower corner arrow.  that is what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This project](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere) is an attempt to backport the holo theme by building it into and Android Library project. You can link that library with your project in order to gain access to the holo theme widgets.

I have never used it but I would think that it contains the spinner widget that you are looking for.